# Is it possible to send data and wait for a response with socket.emit?

Tags: socket.io

From the docs it seems I can run this to wait for a response on the client-side:

```
  // with acknowledgement
  socket.emit("question", (answer) => {
    // ...
  });
```

Or I can send data like so:

```
  // with acknowledgement
  socket.emit("event_type", {
    dataForEvent: "someData"
  });
```

But....how can I combine these? It doesn't seem to be documented if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, yes, you just have to look in the right part of the docs, not only at the emit cheatsheet. https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketemiteventname-args

*eye roll*